# android - How to access/call a method in ActivityClass.java from RecyclerView.Adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I want to call a function in the `ActivityClass.java`, from RecyclerView.Adapter class.

Below is my ActivityClass.java function:

```
public void payslipActivityNav() {

        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        if (b != null) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(HomePage.this, PayslipActivity.class);
            b.putString("UserName", lblUserName.getText().toString());
            b.putString("UserDesignation", lblDesignation.getText().toString());
            intent.putExtras(b);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

And this is the class inside my RecyclerView.Adapter class:

```
    public class SingleItemRowHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            protected TextView tvTitle;

            protected ImageView itemImage;
            protected TextView lblDescription;

            public SingleItemRowHolder(final View view) {
                super(view);

                this.tvTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
                this.itemImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.itemImage);
                this.lblDescription = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lblDescription);


                view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        strSelectedText = tvTitle.getText().toString();
                        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), strSelectedText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        switch (strSelectedText){
                            case "Pay":
                                ((ActivityClass)mContext).payslipActivityNav();
                                break;

                        }




                    }
                });


            }

 }
```

This is the error I am getting `java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to packageName.ActivityClass`

Is there anything wrong with which I am accessing the ActivityClass method? 
Or should the method calling be performed inside that inner class or anywhere else inside the RecyclerView.Adapter class.

Help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:**

I solved it by using this. Something crossed my mind and I tried this and it worked:

```
switch (strSelectedText){
                      case "Pay":
                            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext.getApplicationContext(), ActivityClass.class);
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            mContext.startActivity(intent);
                            break;

                    }
```

Thank You All Of You.

Comment: you can use interface for that purpose

Comment: I only need to call one Activity Method everytime. But if you have a small example for this, it would be helpful.

Comment: @RickyPatel  That means I should use "public static void payslipActivityNav()", INSTEAD OF "public void payslipActivityNav()" ?

Comment: check my ans @ sarthak with interface letme know in case of any query

Comment: check my answer@SarthakSharma

Answer (score 0):

try this : ((YourActivity) context).your_method();//method should be public

Comment: Please refer the code, this is exactly what I am using

Comment: instead of mContext try getActivity() may help in your case

Comment: 'getActivity' is not even listing while typing.. sorry. Also, just want to let you know "private Context mContext;" is declared globally in recycler view adapter class.

Comment: but actually  ((YourActivity) context).your_method();//method should be public ... this should have to work. in my  case it works properly

Comment: you can write this method in common class also and access from   anywhere

Comment: But see the method that I have written on top, its already public. Please have a look.

Comment: write some code in else condition and check is it working...maybe your bundle getting null there.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void payslipActivityNav() {

    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    if (b != null) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(HomePage.this, PayslipActivity.class);
        b.putString("UserName", lblUserName.getText().toString());
        b.putString("UserDesignation", lblDesignation.getText().toString());
        intent.putExtras(b);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

public class SingleItemRowHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

```
        protected TextView tvTitle;

        protected ImageView itemImage;
        protected TextView lblDescription;

        public SingleItemRowHolder(final View view) {
            super(view);

            this.tvTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
            this.itemImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.itemImage);
            this.lblDescription = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lblDescription);


            view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    strSelectedText = tvTitle.getText().toString();
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), strSelectedText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    switch (strSelectedText){
                        case "Pay":
                            ActivityClass.payslipActivityNav();
                            break;

                    }




                }
            });


        }
```

}

Comment: Its giving me the error, "Non-static method 'startActivity(android.content.Intent)' cannot be referenced from a static context"

Comment: public static void payslipActivityNav(Context context) {

    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    if (b != null) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(HomePage.this, PayslipActivity.class);
        b.putString("UserName", lblUserName.getText().toString());
        b.putString("UserDesignation", lblDesignation.getText().toString());
        intent.putExtras(b);
       context.startActivity(intent);
    }
}

pls pass Context in method

Answer (score 0):

You have to use callback interface to do that. And that is the safe way to implement this. Also casting context won't make the code reusable.

You should create an interface inside your adapter and pass the value through it.

Your **adapter** code should be like this:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener;

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {

}

public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener) {
    this.onItemClickListener = onItemClickListener;
}

public void setData(List<AccountProvider> accountProviders) {
    this.accountProviders = accountProviders;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (onItemClickListener != null)
            onItemClickListener.onItemClick(tvTitle.getText().toString());
    }
}
}
```

**Interface:**

```
public interface OnItemClickListener {
      void onItemClick(String value);
}
```

In your **Activity**:

```
public MyActivity implements OnItemClickListener{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter();
    adapter.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    yourRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(String value){
      switch (strSelectedText){
        case "Pay":
          payslipActivityNav();
          break;
       }
    }

}
```

If you need any value from your adapter you can pass it via the interface.

Hope it helps:)

Comment: This is nice, but only if you are calling one method inside the ActivityClass.  But I have a switch case in my Adapter, that means I have to call different functions in the same activity class, according to my needs. What about that?   But thanks for this!

Comment: Its simple do the switch case in your activity and pass the necessary param from adapter. ex: onItemClick(your_param)

Comment: wait, I make changes in my answer for your requirement